# Orthogonal Procrustes Problem Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I'm going through the proof for the [Orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) and I was able to derive all but the last few steps.

Namely, the implication from lines $6 \Rightarrow7 \Rightarrow 8$ (I was able to derive $1 \Rightarrow 6$). I got confused when $\Omega'$ is introduced.

[image]